# Laravel 3 - Order by the division of two fields

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-3

I need following SQL converted to eloquent

```
select * from medias order by likes/views DESC, views ASC
```

I need to use paginate on the result, that is why i prefer eloquent.

Some of my other SQL queries are

```
$media_list = Media::order_by('likes', 'desc')->paginate($per_page);
```

I tried

```
$media_list = Media::order_by('likes/views', 'desc')->paginate($per_page);
```

But it gives error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'likes/views' in 'order clause'
SQL: SELECT * FROM `medias` ORDER BY `likes/views` DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `,` instead of `/`

```
$media_list = Media::order_by('likes,views', 'desc')->paginate($per_page);
```

or

```
$media_list = Media::order_by('likes`,`views', 'desc')->paginate($per_page);
```

And also this is the standard way of doing in laravel

```
$media_list = Media::order_by('likes', 'desc')->orderBy('views', 'desc')->paginate($per_page);

$media_list = DB::table('medias')
    ->select(DB::raw('(likes/views) AS resultant'))
    ->order_by('resultant', 'desc')->orderBy('views', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: ty for updated code<br /> $media_list = DB::table('medias')->select(DB::raw('(likes/views) AS resultant'))->order_by('resultant', 'desc')->order_by('views', 'desc') ->get(); <br />Fails with error <br /> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '(likes/views)' in 'field list'  <br> SQL: SELECT `(likes/views)` AS `resultant` FROM `medias` ORDER BY `resultant` DESC, `views` DESC